# How can I handle errors in #using statement in managed C++ (/CLR)

Tags: c#, c++, .net, interop, managed-c++

I have a managed C++ project (compiled with /CLR) that references a .NET dll by the #using statement, like so:

```
#using <mydotnet.dll>
```

The existence of the dll is tested at compile time, but also at runtime. 
and in the case that the dll is not found at runtime an unhandled exception is thrown:

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'mydotnet, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=n
ull' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at main(Int32 argc, SByte** argv)
   at _mainCRTStartup()

How can I catch this exception? it seems like it runs before the actual code, which makes sense, but I couldn't find another way of ending the program gracefully.

Edit:
I reduced my code to this, which fails to catch any exception:

```
#using <mydotnet.dll>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
    }
    catch (System::IO::FileNotFoundException^ ex)
    {
    }
    catch (System::Exception ^ex)
    {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you,
Roy.

Comment: That error happens inside your `mydotnet.dll`, which means that the reference to `TestManaged` is missing.

Comment: let me elaborate: my managed c++ project (let's call it  cpphost.exe) references mydotnet.dll. if at runtime mydotnet.dll is missing I get the file not found exception, since it can't find the dll.   so the error is not inside mydotnet.dll, but due to it being missing. my question is how do I gracefully handle this situation.  thanks!

Comment: I'm not THAT familiar with c++, but maybe you can check whether you assemblies loaded or not in [AssemblyResolve event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, CLR DLLs are loaded using JIT, so it won't be loaded until the first time code from the DLL is used, which is where the exception will throw. Try putting a `try` `catch` block around the first time the DLL is used, which should catch the error.

```
#using <mydotnet.dll>

...

try{
    // use DLL
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle file not found here
}
```

Comment: I tried catching the exception - I edited my question with the reduced code that doesn't work

Comment: I didn't realise you were working from a completely empty main function. The usage of the DLL in the try block would've been what threw the exception. As one of the comments said on your question, go to [AssemblyResolve event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) to see how to handle it from there.

Comment: This is the most accurate, I was failing to realize that I can't really do it in main.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. 
Thanks for all the help, loading the assembly myself like you suggested works and you can  catch exceptions thrown, but it requires to work with reflection, which is something that I rather avoid.

The problem was that I failed to realize that the #using preprocessor that I was using only affects the compilation unit. and since I used it in main, it worked before any code ran and I had no way of catching exception.
If, on the other hand, I will only use it in a different compilation unit, in a different class for example, the problem will only occur when I instantiate this class and I will be able to catch exceptions.
In case of a missing dll, then a dotnet file not found exception will be thrown which you can catch and handle.

so something like this works:

```
==============  main.cpp ==================

#include "managedclass.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        ManagedClass a;
    }
    catch (System::Exception^ ex)
    {
        //handle exception
    }

    return 0;
}


====================== test.h =================

#pragma once

#using <DotNetLib.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace DotNetLib;

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        auto foo = gcnew SomeClassFromDotNetLib();
    }
};

==========================================
```